# TwimlResponse vs Response in openvbx's twiml.php

Tags: twilio

A number of older plugins use $Response = new Response() instead of what the current plugin documentation shows: $Response = new TwimlResponse;

I created a plugin using openvbx version 1.2, but when pushing to production, version .9, it looks like it doesn't recognize TwimlResponse as a method.

I replaced TwimlResponse with Response, but it looks like .9 doesn't recognize $_REQUEST['From'].  Does anyone know what the method for pulling the call from number was in .9?

Are there any concerns with upgrading our production OpenVBX instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a question of OpenVBX per se but instead the Twilio PHP library behind the scenes. As you've seen, there were a number of updates of the library between those OpenVBX releases which are giving you stress now.

My recommendation is to backup your 0.9 install and do a test upgrade to 1.2.x and if everything works as expected do the real upgrade.